# How can num2str function cut off some digits in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, string-theory

I am reading the book " MATLAB: A practical introductoin programming and problem solving", written by Stormy Attaway and getting curious with the function "num2str".

On page 256, the author used the following steps to convert a number into a string

str2 = num2str(3.456789)

str2=

3.4568

Why are the digits 7 and 9 obmitted? In general, how can we know what the obmitted digits are?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I don't know what Matlab is doing, but it may be rounding $3.456789$ to $4$ decimal places to get $3.4568$ rather than omitting $7$ and $9$.

Comment: Have you tried checking [the documentation for `num2str`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2str.html)? The second option, `num2str(A,precision)`, seems like what you want.